# Maven - activating profiles based on phase/goal

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

Is it possible to activate profile in Maven based on executed phase or goal?
For example when I execute:
mvn deploy
I want my profile activate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate profile based on goal being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964170/how-to-activate-profile-based-on-goal-being-executed)